# Strange ICMP packet

Tags: linux, iptables, icmp

I have an Ubuntu server with iptables that only allows echo request and reply for ICMP and log and drop other ICMP traffic. There is an always on SSH connection between this server and another Ubuntu server using autossh with static IP address on both ends. So the traffic is pretty much predictable between these two servers. Today I saw a very strange ICMP packet:

```
IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=203.0.113.1 DST=203.0.113.5 LEN=96 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=250 ID=59072
PROTO=ICMP TYPE=11 CODE=0 
[SRC=203.0.113.5 DST=203.0.113.10 LEN=360 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=1 ID=56477 PROTO=TCP SPT=3435 DPT=49728 WINDOW=107 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 ]
```

All IPs are public IPs.

My Server IP: 203.0.113.5 (3435 is the ssh port on my server)

Peer Server IP: 203.0.113.10

Packet came from: 203.0.113.1

what is this packet trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

For the IP addresses, if they are private, you do not need to redact them. If you do redact them, please use the [IPv4 addresses reserved for documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) so that we have a least a hint about the network topology.

With the information you have given, the answer to your question *what is this packet trying to do?* is, according to [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792):

```
ICMP type 11 code 0
```

> Description
>
> If the gateway processing a datagram finds the time to live field
> is zero it must discard the datagram.  The gateway may also notify
> the source host via the time exceeded message.
>
> If a host reassembling a fragmented datagram cannot complete the
> reassembly due to missing fragments within its time limit it
> discards the datagram, and it may send a time exceeded message.
>
> If fragment zero is not available then no time exceeded need be
> sent at all.
>
> Code 0 may be received from a gateway.  Code 1 may be received
> from a host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All the IP addresses are public and the fact that in the packet I can see it tries to probably initiate another connection with source being my sever and destination being the only server that connects to my ssh port concerns me. So It seems to be trying to fool the peers firewall that this is a packet from an established ssh connection coming from the server you are connected to, even the same ssh port.